# How to disable given date in default calendar?

Tags: magento-1.7, date, datepicker, calendar

I have a table in the database which contains some dates. I want to disable those dates in magento default calendar. The calendar is in front-end checkout process (used to add delivery date for the order). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have not done this myself, so this is a guide to get you in the right direction.

the calendar used by magento is located here : /js/calendar/calendar.js, and from its header comments, you will find it is done by http://www.dynarch.com/, and the docs is located here : http://www.dynarch.com/jscal

You will see there is built in functionality (via a callback) to disable dates. (http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/#sec8)

> You can also disable individual dates by supplying a callback function
>   which receives a JS date object and returns true if that date must be 
>   disabled, or false otherwise.    .....suppose you have in your
>   database a list of dates that should be  disabled, just convert them
>   to numeric value and build up a hash  table, then your `disabled()`
>   handler can very conveniently return true  for them:

(sound just like what you want/have ;) )

```
var DISABLED_DATES = {
    20090502: true,
    20090505: true,
    20090510: true,
    20090511: true
};
Calendar.setup({
    cont     : "sample3",
    disabled : function(date) {
        date = Calendar.dateToInt(date);
        return date in DISABLED_DATES;
    }
});
```

To extend magento calendar creation, you need to create your own class, which extends the core `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Date` class, which will allow you to adjust the setup for the calendar, and include your dates. You will need to override the `getElementHtml()` method, which contains the calandar setup script code.

```
$html .= sprintf('
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                Calendar.setup({
                    inputField: "%s",
                    ifFormat: "%s",
                    showsTime: %s,
                    button: "%s_trig",
                    align: "Bl",
                    singleClick : true
                });
            //]]>
            </script>',
            $this->getHtmlId(), $displayFormat,
            $this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false', $this->getHtmlId()
        );
```

and include the callback and dates you have, as per the calendar docs.

I am not sure how you are displaying the calendars in your site, but one way to use the custom class in a form is to create a custom form element as such:

```
$this->getForm()->addType('customDate','ProxiBlue_GiftPromo_Data_Form_Element_Date');
```

Hope this helps you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try on this and if it worked I'll put the source here.

Comment: How did this go? Got it working?

Answer (score 2):

Now We will DISABLE past Dates.
Solution:

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Date.php
(it is advisable to add custom calendar template, as in any upgrade you will lose your modifications)

Use the folowing to disable the previous dates:

```
//<![CDATA[
           var calendarSetupObject = {
                inputField  : "' . $this->getId() . '",
                ifFormat    : "' . $displayFormat . '",
                showsTime   : "' . ($this->getTime() ? 'true' : 'false') . '",
                button      : "' . $this->getId() . '_trig",
                align       : "Bl",
                singleClick : true,
                disableFunc: function(date)  {
                    var now= new Date();
                    if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
                    if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
                    if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <   now.getDate())  { return true; } }
                },
            }';
```

Comment: This will disable all of the past days and also all of the days before the current day from the future months from next year and after :)